# Argument '<controller>' is not a function in Angular routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngroute

I'm getting this error and I cannot locate the problem, following is my error

`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'homeCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/ng/areq?p0=homeCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at VALIDITY_STATE_PROPERTY (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:7703:12)
    at assertArg (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9134:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9144:3)
    at $get (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14903:9)
    at updateView (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:42986:30)
    at IonicModule.directive.directive.compile (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:42942:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14336:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13730:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14330:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13730:13)`

Following is my Angular and Ionic project:

```
#app.js
angular.module('ft', ['ionic', 'ft.controllers'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  // run method
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/sideMenu.html',
    controller: 'menuCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});

#www/js/controllers/home_ctrl.js
angular.module('ft.controllers', [])
  .controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout){

  });

#index.html file
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/home_ctrl.js"></script>
```

But if I remove the `homeCtrl` from routes, it works fine. I spent fair amount of time now and for me it seems ok.

Comment: Can you verify, without a doubt, that the browser is able to download the `home_ctrl.js` file?

Comment: i ran it in plnkr, no errors: http://plnkr.co/edit/7eSdX3nE0CKHqomgMEoh?p=preview

Comment: OP, i think your home_ctrl.js location is wrong

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, thanks for the answer. `home_ctrl.js` is accessible from the browser, the issue was in duplication of module loading. I posted an answer with details

Comment: @NoIdeaForName, thanks for the answer , home_ctrl.js is accessible from the browser, the issue was in duplication of module loading. I posted an answer with details

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `bundling & minification`, try:

```
var app = angular.module('ft.controllers', []);
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicModal', '$timeout', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
});
```

Minification of the JS code replaces variables name. `AngularJS` does it's injection of modules based on this names.

Comment: No, that is valid initialization.

Comment: Unfortunately that's still not the problem. Angular is unable to find the controller because it's not being loaded.

Comment: How can that not be a problem when you're using minification? How can the controller be found if it's signature is changed by the minification process?

Comment: Minification doesn't change the name of the controller itself, just the injected parameter names, and even then they are changed in all referenced locations. Minification is not the issue.

Comment: That is not true. Angular injects by parameter name.

Comment: You're right - I didn't state that correctly. My point is this - the OP's issue is unrelated to minification because that wouldn't cause the controller name to be missing.

Comment: Now that we cleared my initial misconception can you remove the down-vote? My suggestion is useful if the OP uses minification as I'm suspecting.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu, thanks for the answer. It was an issue with initializing the modules, I posted an answer with details.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to fix the issue, The problem was `ft.controllers` is used in two controllers.

```
angular.module('ft.controllers', [])
  .controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout){
  });

angular.module('ft.controllers', [])
.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout){
]});
```

When I changed the names to `ft.controllers.home`, `ft.controllers.menu` and added them to `app.js` it started working

How ever I thought it will work as I believe the same this is used in `ionic` `sideMenu` started app

```
#controllers.js from ionic started sideMenu app
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
})

.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
})
```

[controllers.js file](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu/blob/master/js/controllers.js)

[app.js file](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu/blob/master/js/app.js)

[project](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu)

Comment: Bear in mind you could actually define the module in the `app.js` file like this `angular.module('ft.controllers', [])` and then add the controllers wherever like this `angular.module('ft.controllers').controller(...)`. Notice the second call doesn't send an array - that becomes a *get* instead of *define*.